# "Elkrem:" Does it install an Ethereum client on a micro-controller?

Tags: nodes, light-clients, clients, iot

I have read this article which describes the prototype of **Ethkrem**, a development board for IOT and Ethereum: https://devpost.com/software/elkrem-development-board-for-iot-ethereum .

However, it is not clear to me that this platform installs an Ethereum light client (Geth or Parity) on their micro-controller? Or they install Ethereum client on a routing connected to this micro-controller? like this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BrvGnuGteI ?

Is it possible to install an Ethereum light client on `Nano Pi` using **EthArmbian**? (https://docs.armbian.com/#supported-boards)

**Note:** EthArmbian is a custom Linux image for ARM SoC devices that runs Geth or Parity Ethereum clients as a boot service and automatically turns your ARM SoC into an full Ethereum node. (https://github.com/diglos/userpatches#etharmbian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Islam from Elkrem.

Our board has 2 processors. One of them is used solely for running `go-ethereum` client in light mode. The other is a bare-metal user programmable microcontroller. Both are interconnected with an RPC system over UART.

The board also has a WiFi module, a microSD card slot, a secure microcontroller and a usb port.

We've run `go-ethereum` in light mode successfully before on Nano Pi without using **EthArmbian**